# How to pop all screens repeatedly till only two screens remain in the stack other than the current screen?

Tags: flutter

I have like 10 screens in my stack right now. On pressing logout button, I just need first two screens on my stack and pop all the screens above it.

Comment: why don't you set your target VC as rootViewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName))
```